# how to pass the values to new window using jsp in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

```
<a href="printAllocation.action?event=printAllocation&amp;fundAlias=%{fundAlias}&amp;fundName=%{fundName}&amp;lendFromMonth=%{lendFromMonth}&amp;lendFromYear=%{lendFromYear}&amp;partListDate=%{partListDate}&amp;partListType=%{partListType}&amp;secLendIncome=%{secLendIncome}"
onClick="NewWindow(this.href,'Warning','1000','800','Yes');return false;">
            <s:submit value="Print" cssClass="btnRedApple">
            </s:submit></a>
```

Hi! in the above code I'm trying to pass the values from the current jsp to new window by using *anchor* tag for the button **"print"** but in new window I'm not getting the values.

This is done for the **struts2** migration so can any one please help me in resolving this issue. how can I pass the value to the new window

Comment: Also would be helpful to see NewWindow function of your javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a URL with many parameters. What makes it worse is including the URL in anchor tag. I suggest you use `s:url` of stuts 2.

> Struts 2 “url” tag is used to create an URL and output it as a text
>   format. It’s never work by itself, but it can provides URL to other
>   tags like  to create a hyperlink or  to render an image

```
<s:url action="printAllocation.action" var="urlTagValue" >
    <s:param name="event">printAllocation</s:param>
    <s:param name="fundAlias" value="%{fundAlias}"></s:param>
    <s:param name="fundName" value="%{fundName}"></s:param>
    ...//all the other parameters
</s:url>
```

this essentailly  generates output in text format like below.

```
/theDomainOfYourWebApp/printAllocation.action?event=printAllocation&fundAlias=...
```

Add then use it your anchor tag

```
<a href="<s:property value="#urlTagValue" />" onClick="NewWindow(this.href,'Warning','1000','800','Yes');return false;>URL Tag Action (via property)</a>
```

Comment: thanks a lot i tried in this way and it worked out..:)